# What is etymology of the term "right up the Wazoo"?

Tags: etymology

I'm sure everyone here has heard the expression "right up the Wazoo", meaning "in large or excessive quantities, to disgusting excess". I was wondering if anyone knew exactly where "the Wazoo" actually is?

Comment: Hmm, I always thought this was just a euphemism for "right up the ass". Strange. **Edit:** Wikipedia [insists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazoo) that there is a Wazoo in Washington, another one serving Kentucky and Indiana, and even a fictional one in Alabama.

Comment: I've always heard it as "out the wazoo".

Comment: See also: "out the Yin-Yang" or "up the Yin-Yang". "Same difference" as my grade 7 math teacher used to say...

Comment: I also believe it is a euphemism for "up the ass" or "out the ass".  I think you can use that to mean "in large or excessive quantities", as well.  I think the fact that Wazoo is a place doesn't call any of that into question.  (I am guessing it was probably just chosen because it is a funny sounding word.)

Comment: The existence of Wazoo, Washington probably has no more to do with the phrase origin than Hell, Michigan has to do with any hell-related phrases.

Comment: @mickeyf: "4 minus 3" and "6 minus 5" - that's some same difference right there!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both *up* and *out* can be used in conjunction with *the wazoo*, and both imply too much of something. In this context, the wazoo is a slang term for the anus. The etymology of the term is uncertain. I have always felt that *up the wazoo* implied a more unpleasant situation than *out the wazoo*, but I'm sure that is simply a matter of personal preference. [cough].

Wiktionary has identical definitions for each term, and also makes note of the similarity to the phrase *up/out the [ying-yang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_the_ying_yang)* [sic].

[**up the wazoo**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up_the_wazoo)
1. (vulgar, idiomatic) up the ass; excessive or excessively; too much
e.g.: *I'd go, but I'm sure they will charge up the wazoo for tickets.*

[**out the wazoo**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_the_wazoo)
1. (vulgar, idiomatic) out the ass; excessive or excessively; too much
e.g.: *I planted a few seeds and had radishes out the wazoo within a month.*

---

An [article](http://www.cjr.org/language_corner/out_the_wazoo.php) in the Columbia Journalism Review provides some possible explanations for the origin of both the phrase and the word itself:

> ... the venerable Oxford English Dictionary weighs in. While it professes not to know the origin of “wazoo,” it says that others suspect it may come from the French oiseau, or bird, through a Louisiana Creole term, “razoo,” for raspberry. (Those with particularly fertile dirty minds may be able to make the connection.) It’s almost exclusively American.
>
> The OED’s first two citations are telling in themselves. The first, in 1961, is from a University of California, Berkeley publication: “Run it up yer ol’ wazoo!” Its second citation is from a publication not known for its use of slang, The Wall Street Journal, in 1971: “Golf itself is quite safe, the greatest risk being the possibility of a long drive plunking some poor fellow in the wazoo.”

A [post](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/09/wazoo-story.html) on grammarphobia.com mentions another possibility:

> The Cassell’s Dictionary of Slang suggests that “wazoo” as a euphemism might be a variation on “gazoo” and “kazoo,” which had been put to similar uses in the 1960s. The OED also notes the similarities between the terms, and has citations for this slang usage of both “gazoo” (1965) and “kazoo” (1973).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazoo) offers a different explanation but, sadly, offers no reference or citation of any kind:

> Slang for anus Originally derived from the Pama-Nyungan languages (the family of Indigenous Australian languages), and thought to refer to the anus of an animal, particularly the kangaroo.

Answer (score 2):

Where I'm from in Georgia, "Out to Wazoo" means something that is so far away or intangible that someone would have to travel to "Wazoo" to get it. The Washington State University, WSU (colloquially referred to as Wazzu), is in Pullman, WA, in the completely opposite corner of the country from Georgia. I don't know if these have similar origins, but that's how I have always understood the term.

Comment: Hmmm. You may be on to something there.